# Accumulator on parallel stream reduction is always called only with identity

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm using the three-argument version of Stream#reduce. Starting with a list of strings, and 0 as the *identity*, the *accumulator* adds the identity and length of the string. The *combiner* adds two partial results.

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
IntStream.range(0, 10)
            .forEach(i -> strings.add("a"));

System.out.println(strings.stream()
    .parallel()
    .reduce(0,
            (res, s) -> {
                System.out.println("Accumulator called with " + res + " and " + s);
                return res + s.length();
            },
            (a, b) -> {
                System.out.println("Combiner called with " + a + " and " + b);
                return a + b;
            }));
```

When running this `Accumulator called with 0 and a` is printed 10 times whereas summing of partial results happen *only* in the combiner like,

```
Combiner called with 1 and 1
Combiner called with 1 and 2
....
Combiner called with 2 and 3
Combiner called with 5 and 5
```

Why isn't the accumulator called with a previous (non-identity) result and a string i.e., why don't we see a print statement like `Accumulator called with 1 and a`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example is working with a small data set. We need to have a lot of elements to see this behaviour (also depends on the capacity of the machine in which the code is run).

For instance, creating 100 strings and running this, I can see `Accumulator called with 1 and a` printed.

Greater the number of elements, greater the number of times the accumulator will be called repeatedly for accumulation.